# Create Eth / IP packets in Java

Tags: java, udp, ip

I need to create an Ethernet packet with existing UDP payload. I need to put in the ports / checksum for UDP, IP's/checksum for IP layer etc. Is there any library for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556829/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets-using-java

Comment: Not really. That's a simple create / send UDP to a socket. I am using pcap. I have a custom payload, a protocol over UDP. The stack is Ethernet-IP-UDP-something else

Comment: I tried parsing a Wireshark packet (ethernet level) with Jnetpcap. It decodes the ethernet header alright but does not get the IP level details, it returns ipHeader as null. Has anyone tried this before?