# Java: send JSON over UDP

Tags: java, json, networking, stream, udp

how do I send a JSONObject in Java over UDP?

For TCP I use my following code:

```
private OutputStreamWriter outStreamW;

public void sendToConsumer(JSONObject jsonOb, Socket tcpSocket) {
    try {
        outStreamW = new OutputStreamWriter(tcpSocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        outStreamW.write(jsonOb.toString() + "\n");
        outStreamW.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However I miss the approach as I implement it over UDP

Comment: This doesn't strike me like you spent any time trying to find a solution yourself.
http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: As an aside to your question, I don't think you should want to send JSON over UDP. You could potentially lose data in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) serialize the JSON (e.g. convert to string)

2) divide in packets depending on the size (e.g. split the string)

3) [send UDP packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556829/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets-using-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The receiver might receive only a few packets and, even if it receives all, it does in whatever order. You might want to add some leading number like 1/5 2/5 3/5 etc in case you have 5 packets. This is just an idea. I would stick to TCP.

Also, you would have to add some timeout within the deserialization logic.