# How to receive Broadcast message in java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, broadcasting

I am new to the area of computer networks so please bear with me. Below is the code I am using to broadcast datapacket over internet from the server but I do not know how to receive the broadcasted message at client side. Can anybody help me with that?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class broadcast_message {
    private static DatagramSocket socket = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        broadcast("Hello", InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"));
        System.out.println("Sent");
    }

    public static void broadcast(String broadcastMessage, InetAddress address) throws IOException {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setBroadcast(true);

        byte[] buffer = broadcastMessage.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket packet 
          = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, 4000);
        socket.send(packet);
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code sends a message to a port, but no one is there to receive it.

You need to create a socket listener to the same port (4000), before you send the message so that your socket listener receives the message.

See this post for example: [sending and receiving UDP packets using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556829/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

i think this should help -

```
package com.AK_Tech.MyBroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //your code    
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.